# Internet Explorer Tabbed Browsing Setting Not Opening Document in New Tab

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

While visiting a website, I notice this behavior on my PC.  I have set up a simple example to illustrate.

Let's say I have a webpage which has two links.  The first is a link to a document on a website.  The other is  a link to a document on a file share.  When I click the first link, the document on the website is opened in a new Internet Explorer window.  When I click the second link, the document on the file share is opened in a new tab.  Both have a target attribute set to blank.

Here is a basic sample of the HTML.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://myWebsite/documents/someDocument.pdf" target="_blank">Link 1</a><br>
        <a href="file://myServer/folder/someOtherDocument.pdf" target="_blank">Link 2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the document on Link 1 to open in a new tab as it does for Link 2.  I have done some homework and I know this involves the Tabbed Browsing Settings in IE on my machine.  As you can see below, I have it set to *Always open pop-ups in a new tab*.

[image]

Thus, why is the document on the website not automatically opening in a new tab?  I know I may right-click and select *Open in new tab* or click the middle mouse button/scroll wheel,  but I would like to know why the tabbed browsing setting is not working.  For the record, I am using Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Which PDF reader's IE plugin are you using? Maybe another one will work as expected?

Comment: I am using Adobe Reader X.  Based on your suggestion I tried FoxIt Reader.  It had the same results.  It opens the website document in a new window and the file share document in a new tab.

Comment: In IE, go to `Internet Options / Security` and disable Protected Mode, then close and relaunch the browser. Does that change anything?

Comment: Protected Mode was the culprit. If you would, please post your comment as an answer, and I'll give you credit. I moved the website in the link to the trusted zone and disabled protected mode on the trusted zone.  It has been working great ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling IE's **Protected Mode** under `Internet Options / Security`, since it may be causing this. Adobe Reader X onwards also has its own Protected Mode which you can read about [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/asset/2010/10/inside-adobe-reader-protected-mode-part-1-design.html).